# Firebase Paging Recycler Adapter Giving Error?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

So I trying to Retrieve data to the recycler view with Paginated Adapter using Firebase Ui-Database. But I keep giving me Error, Stuck on This for more than a Week. i think there is error in query.

[image: This is the Database Architecture Photo, Do Check]

So the Model class is TeachersHelper To Retrieve Data.

Firebase paginated Adapter:

```
public class teacher_adapter extends FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter<TeachersHelper, teacher_adapter.ExampleViewHolder> {

    // variables to handle onclicks and dataloading
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Context ctx;


    // constructor
    public teacher_adapter(@NonNull DatabasePagingOptions<TeachersHelper> options,
                           ProgressBar progressBar, Context ctx) {
        super(options);
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        return new ExampleViewHolder(view, mListener);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExampleViewHolder holder, int position,
                                    @NonNull TeachersHelper model) {

        TeachersHelper currentItem = model;
 
        // setting image
        String imageLink = currentItem.getImage();
        
        // Image assigning
        if (currentItem.getImage().equals("No")) {
            holder.iconName.setImageResource(R.drawable.profilepicture);
        } else {
            Picasso.get().load(imageLink).into(holder.iconName);
        }
        holder.individualName.setText(currentItem.gettName());
        holder.departmentOrstudentstuff.setText(currentItem.gettDepartment());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLoadingStateChanged(@NonNull LoadingState state) {
        switch (state) {
            case LOADING_INITIAL:
                // The initial load has begun
                // ...
            case LOADING_MORE:
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                // The adapter has started to load an additional page
                // ...
            case LOADED:
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                // The previous load (either initial or additional) completed
                // ...
            case ERROR:
                StyleableToast.makeText(ctx, "Error Try Again", R.style.exampleToast).show();
                // The previous load (either initial or additional) failed. Call
                // the retry() method in order to retry the load operation.
                // ...
        }
    }

    public static class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView iconName;
        public TextView individualName;
        public TextView departmentOrstudentstuff;

        public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView, final teacher_adapter.OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);
            iconName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profilePic_listView);
            individualName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.studentsName_Listview);
            departmentOrstudentstuff = itemView.findViewById(R.id.student_Registrattion_listview);
        }
    }
}
```

Mainactivity:

retrieving Data

```
     // query
    Query baseQuery = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("Admin").child(mAuth.getUid()).child("INSTITUTE")
            .child("TEACHERS").child("TEACHERINFORMATION");

     //I think I have an error in defining the query


    PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
            .setPrefetchDistance(10)
            .setPageSize(20)
            .build();


    // The options for the adapter combine the paging configuration with query information
    // and application-specific options for lifecycle, etc.
    DatabasePagingOptions<TeachersHelper> options = new DatabasePagingOptions.Builder<TeachersHelper>()
            .setLifecycleOwner(this)
            .setQuery(baseQuery, config, TeachersHelper.class)
            .build();

   // assiging the adapter
    teacher_adapter = new teacher_adapter(options, bottomProgressbar, teacher_admin.this);
    teacher_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

ONSTART and ONSTOP:

```
  @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    teacher_adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    teacher_adapter.stopListening();
}
```

This is giving the ERROR Loading data TOAST Which is defined Adapter.

Comment: Please be mindful that text in all-caps is perceived as yelling by most people. Instead can you edit your question to show the actual error message you get when you run this code?

Comment: sorry i was just trying to highlight, its showing the toast from the onLoadingstate Changed error loading data from the Adapter

Comment: No it didn’t  workout using a wrapper class. What i did is  i removed the complex node structure i.e, i just started inserting data under Teachers node with push id’s . Then it worked out fine. Thank you frank .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using simple database architecture. What is did is removed the  Teacherinformation node and started inserting data below pushid it worked out fine .

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the reference as:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("Admin").child(mAuth.getUid()).child("INSTITUTE")
            .child("TEACHERS").child("TEACHERINFORMATION");
```

But there is no child `TEACHERINFORMATION` directly under `TEACHERS` in your database, so that reference points to no data in your database.

My guess it that you want the adapter to show the data under `TEACHERS`:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference("Admin").child(mAuth.getUid()).child("INSTITUTE")
            .child("TEACHERS");
```

And then for each child node, it should show the `TEACHERINFORMATION` child. This means that `TEACHERINFORMATION` needs to be a part of the Java class you use to map the `DataSnapshot` to your application code.

So if your current `TeachersHelper` contains the `image`, `tDepartment` and other properties of `TEACHERINFORMATION`, you can create a wrapper class for that:

```
public class TeacherWrapper {
   @PropertyName("TEACHERINFORMATION")
   public TeachersHelper TEACHERINFORMATION;
}
```

Pass this class into your adapter:

```
.setQuery(baseQuery, config, TeacherWrapper.class)
```

And then modify your other code to pick up the nested data from the wrapper.